# Android - after notifyDataSetChanged ListView remains blank

Tags: java, android

It's hours I search for something, but it doesn't seem to help.. Android Studio doesn't launch any error, but the screen remains blank. Why?

```
package org.newapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import saxrssreader.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayAdapter<RssItem> rssItemsArrayAdapter;
    ListView codeLearnLessons;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RssItem[] rssItems = new RssItem[]{};
        rssItemsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rssItems);
        new WebCall().execute(rssItems);
        codeLearnLessons = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        codeLearnLessons.setAdapter(rssItemsArrayAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class WebCall extends AsyncTask<RssItem, Void, Void>  {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(RssItem... items) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.somewpsite.com/feed");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ArrayList<RssItem> listItems = RssReader.read(url).getRssItems();
                items = listItems.toArray(new RssItem[listItems.size()]);
                final int l = items.length;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        codeLearnLessons.invalidateViews();
                        rssItemsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Log.i("rec", "rec" + l);
                    }
                });
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            /*ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mDialog.show();*/
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: RssItems is probably empty, so the adapter has no data to display. Check the length of rssItems after your webCall.execute() method.

Comment: It's checked in here: Log.i("rec", "rec" + l); l is 15

Comment: Again, check the length of rssItems _After_ your webCall.execute() method. It will be 0, as others have stated below, because you're creating a new array instead of updating the rssItems array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your using a ArrayList which only has scope inside of the `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` method.  Since it is not given to the adapter, the `notifyDataSetChanged()` does nothing.  You'll need to replace the existing array like this:

```
rssItemsArrayAdapter.clear();
rssItemsArrayAdapter.addAll(listItems);
rssItemsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Having said that, you also really need to change your use of `AsyncTask`.  There's no need to call `runOnUiThread()` from within your `doInBackground()` as the `AsyncTask` will automatically run its `onPostExecute()` on the UI thread.  Have your `doInBackground()` method return your new `ArrayList<RssItem>` and create an `onPostExecute()` override method which adjusts the adapter as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your items to the AsyncTask but in the AsyncTask you declare them new with the content of your result. You never pass the items to your ArrayAdapter back. Make them a property of your class instance.

Edit - Example:

```
rssItemsArrayAdapter.clear();
rssItemsArrayAdapter.addAll(items);
```

and afterwards

```
rssItemsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I don't get it sorry, how do I do it? Isn't this line: items = listItems.toArray(new RssItem[listItems.size()]); fulfilling the items variable?

Comment: You do not change the items in the ArrayAdapter, I included some example code in the answer